# Binding to a Property of UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I wrote a widget that contains lots of stuff, and it contains a property (DependencyProperty) that is being updated from inside the UC class (based on input being typed into a textbox and input from button clicks etc..) Its definition is :

```
public partial class UserControlClassName : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    } 

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(UserControlClassName), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnValueChanged));

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("new value: " + e.NewValue);
        }
    }

   ...
   ...
   lots of other code that updates the Value property..
   ...
   ...

}
```

I'm instantiating the UC in some window's XAML as follows:

```
<GeneralControls:UserControlClassName
            x:Name="someRandomName"
            Value="{Binding MyViewModel.MyBoundedValueField, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource DebugBinding}}"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

And to complete the picture, this is the view model's property i'm using to "grab" the value :

```
public string MyBoundedValueField
    {
        get { return myBoundedValueField; }
        set
        {
            if (myBoundedValueField!= value)
            {
                myBoundedValueField = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyBoundedValueField");
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is- the Value property that inside the user control **do** get updated, but the outer property i'm binding to in the xaml (myBoundedValueField ) is not getting the updates.. something with the binding to this dependency property is not working- so I attached a converter to debug this and the converter does not get called so its definitely a wrong binding setup..

(Tnx to any1 who help!)

Comment: A Binding Path like `MyViewModel.MyBoundedValueField` without setting a Source or RelativeSource would require an object with a public `MyViewModel` property in the DataContext of the UserControl or one of its parent controls. Besides that, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged isn't necessary for dependency properties. So you could remove a lot of redundant stuff from your code.

Comment: I need the user control to be able to "attach" to any input binding field I will provide in the xaml (like widgets do) - must I pass in the DataContext?

Comment: You should certainly pass an instance of `MyViewModel` to the UserControl's DataContext and change the binding path to `{Binding MyBoundedValueField, ...}`.

Comment: (regarding the INotifyPropertyChanged - you right! removing..)

Comment: how can this be done from within the xaml?

Comment: In common scenarios (e.g. in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl) a UserControl will inherit its data object (i.e. the source object of its bindings) by inheriting the value of the DataContext property of its parent. If you have a main view model, you would typically assign the MainWindow's DataContext to an instance of the view model, like `<Window.DataContext><local:MyViewModel></Window.DataContext>`.

Comment: I can see the DataContext inside the UC is the same as the Window's DataContext. (debugged and checked now) - Its not clear to my why this type of binding not working: {Binding MyViewModel.MyBoundedValueField}   --  should I set the Datacontext of the UC in the XAML to MyViewModel like this : DataContext={Binding MyViewModel} ?

Comment: And that is an instance of the (view model) class that has the `MyBoundedValueField` property? The binding path should then be just `MyBoundedValueField` not `MyViewModel.MyBoundedValueField`.

Comment: no- its a view model that contains lots of class instances that hold the data- MyViewModel is only one class of many others..

Comment: Well, I can't guess what you actually have. `MyViewModel` might as well be a public property of your "main" view model. You haven't shown that in your question.

Comment: `MyViewModel` is just a datacontainer - I've just set in the xaml the following: `DataContext={Binding MyViewModel}`  and changed the binding of Value to `Value="{Binding MyBoundedValueField}"` and still, The Value prop do gets changed - MyBoundedValueField is not

Comment: how can I debug the binding to `MyBoundedValueField` ?

Comment: As already said, `DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}"` implies that `MyViewModel` is a public property in some "outer" view model. Check the Output Windows in Visual Studio for binding error messages.

Comment: no errors in the log regarding this specific class :\ i'm hopeless

Comment: its fixed! The problem was in the xaml I had to add Mode=TwoWay -no idea why it works only in 2 way binding.. isn't the default 1 way? so at least it gets updated in one direction?!

Comment: I would like to thank you for your assistance and time!

Comment: If you solved the problem please be sure to create an answer so other people know it's complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution eventually was to add Mode=TwoWay

```
<GeneralControls:UserControlClassName
    x:Name="someRandomName"
    Mode=TwoWay
    Value="{Binding MyViewModel.MyBoundedValueField, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource DebugBinding}}"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

I don't know as to why the binding did not work without it - I would love to hear an explanation if any1 can shade some light on the subject..

Special thanks to @Clemens!!!